# Proving that f(n) = o(g(n)) implies 2^f(n) = o(2^g(n))

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, proof

I can't find a counterexample to this, but I do not know a formal way of proving it. Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

This is "little-o" notation by the way. So a strict upper bound

f(n) = o(g(n)) implies $ 2^{f(n)} = o(2^{g(n}) $

Comment: This site doesn't have MathJax enabled.

Comment: Meant to post in math.stackexchange *facepalm*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need help proving that if f(n) = O(g(n)) implies 2^(f(n)) = O(2^g(n)))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361448/i-need-help-proving-that-if-fn-ogn-implies-2fn-o2gn)

Comment: Well it's not exactly a duplicate because I'm asking about little-o notation which is different from big o. But I suppose that post helps me a little bit

Comment: @ehhpitome I think https://cs.stackexchange.com is more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counter-example:

```
f(n) = 1/n
g(n) = 1
```

We have: `f(n)/g(n) -> 0` when `n -> oo`, so `f` and `g` verifies: `f(n) = o(g(n))`.

But:

```
2^f(n) = 2^(1/n) -> 1 when n -> oo
2^g(n) = 2^1     -> 2 when n -> oo
```

And this leads to:

```
[2^f(n)]/[2^g(n)] -> 1/2 when n -> oo
```

This proves that `2^f(n) != o(2^g(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to make correction here, i came across my old notes and realize that what i have stated is completely wrong.

explanation is as following:

lets say f(n)=2n and g(n)=n;

so according to the given problem
take power both sides and it will be

- 2^2n=2^n;
- 2^n*2^n=2^n;
- and it is not satisfying the asymptotic condition because left hand side is no constantly comparable to the right hand side.

Comment: The `o()` vanished between the first and second point, which needs to be justified, since sleight of hand is not a valid proof technique.

Comment: But if you choose f(n) = 2n and g(n) = n, f(n) is not o(g(n))

Comment: f(n)=o(g(n)) means      f(n)<g(n)  i.e.  f(n)<c* (g(n)) where c is a constant and for all values of c>2 this equation will hold true.

Comment: According to the [definition of little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) the limit of f(n)/g(n) as n->infinity must equal = 0. It doesn't when you choose those values for f(n) and g(n)